# How should I use Laravel Eloquent queries and use relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a **`User`** model which *`belongsTo`* a **`Department`**.

So Department got *id* and *name* fields.

At the User model I got:

```
public function department() {

      return $this->belongsTo('Department');
}
```

That way I can do something like: `Auth::user()->department->name` getting the actual name of the department user belongs to.

However, when I'm calling some users, I can't figure out best way to get multiple rows containing its department attribute with a name.

I wrote:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user -> department = Department::find($user->department_id)->name;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **eager load** related models so they are loaded for all users with only one database query and will be included in JSON output:

```
$users = User::with('department')->get();
```

[More about eager loading in the Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: Could you extend your answer a bit, maybe include some other relationships cases?

Comment: Please read the docs first. If you have already, can you be a bit more specific in what's unclear?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got the relationship between User Model and Department Model already. So you can call it like you did with Auth().

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->department->name ;
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly the point, I want to return an array with the whole users.

Comment: you want to list all users in a view with department name, right?

Comment: And it's actually an AJAX what I'm doing, not a view generation

Comment: please this one  `$user->department_name = $user->department->name ;` inside the `foreach`

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm doing :)